# Apache Camel OSGi container configured by Java DSL?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-camel

I need to integrate an Apache-camel application with an OSGi Container. It would be helpful to me as this integration is configurable through Java DSL.

So far I have test Apache Karaf as best suitable solution, since it is as lightweight as it's needed for my implementation.

Yet I am seeking a related OSGi Server that can integrate as perfect as Karaf with Apache-Camel.

Cheers!

Comment: Why can't you use karaf?

Comment: I will use Karaf since it's the best solution so far. But I would like to mind more solutions.

Answer (score 3):

We've been using servicemix esb  - it seems pretty lightweight as it is basically karaf which deploys camel applications as osgi bundles.

The approach I was going to go with was create a spring application context and create the camel context and reference the java dsl route builders in that. When you deploy the module it will look for spring context and automatically start it up like [this](http://servicemix.apache.org/32-using-the-camel-java-dsl-for-the-first-time.html).

Comment: I think ServiceMix uses Karaf or a part of ServiceMix is Karaf itself. Correct me if I am wrong. I have thought this solution as well, yet a Spring integration is last in my list for architectural purposes.

Comment: Yes - it embeds karaf. It's not "Spring Integration" - it's just a camel context that is created by spring.

Comment: ServiceMix is probably the best tested and well suited way to go as you say, since it more or less is built for camel